# Finding the position of a specified string in another string

Tags: vb.net

I need to find the position of a changing specified word in a string, and I need it to be very specific so it doesn't include words without spaces so say if I was looking for the word 'Hi' It would only return true if it was checking 'Hi' and not 'HiExample'.

Code:

```
Dim userString As String = userInput.Text
    userString = userString.ToLower()

    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim wordString = userString.ToLower().Split(" "c)
    Dim iList As New List(Of String)()

    For Each word In wordString
        If d.ContainsKey(word) Then
            d(word) += 1
            iList.Add(word)
        Else
            d.Add(word, 1)
        End If
    Next

    For Each de In d
        For i As Integer = 0 To wordString.Count - 1
            Dim index As Integer = userString.IndexOf(de.Key)
            output.Text &= "Word: " & de.Key & " Occurrence: " & de.Value & " Position: " & GET POSTION OF EACH WORD HERE & Environment.NewLine
        Next
    Next
```

Checking for upper case or lower case will not be necessary as I have already converted the string into lower case.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: do you know about regular expressions? Could be useful here

Answer (score 0):

you can try Regex

```
For Each de In d
   Dim index As Integer = Regex.Matches(userString, "(?<=^|\b|\s)" & Regex.Escape(de.Key) & "(?=\s|\b|$)")(0).Index
   Console.WriteLine("Word: " & de.Key & " Occurrence: " & de.Value & " Position: " & index)
Next
```

this might get you started